# Sphinx directory structure for rst and html generated

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

I have been working on setting up auto documentation for my Python files, which are in a large hierarchy of directory structure. I am able to generate rst and html files for all of them with my scripts and by using autodoc module. I was wondering if it is possible to generate rst and html files in the same directory structure/hierarchy of directories as my Python files.

eg., the relative path of my python file is: python/common/element.py;
     the rst file generated is: python.common.element.rst;
     and same for html.
I want it to form the same directory structure as for py files, like: 
  sphinx/_build/rst/python/common/element.rst
& sphinx/_build/html/python/common/element.html

PS: I am working on ubuntu-14.04 and Sphinx-1.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Source and build directories must be separate. See the [options to `sphinx-build`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#invocation-of-sphinx-build).

You could write a script to post-process the output, moving files from the build directory into another.

Comment: Yes obviously the source and build directories will be different. But my question was to do it inside the build directory itself. Anyways, I will write a script for the same then, to move and arrange files after sphinx-build.

Comment: The answer is still no, as each output format has its own subdirectory within the build directory. A post-processing script is your only option.